# HTMLPurifier Breaking Images

Tags: php, xss, ckeditor, htmlpurifier

I'm trying to run HTMLPurifier on user input from a WYSIWYG (CK Editor) and the images are breaking.

Unfiltered Input:

```
<img alt="laugh" src="/lib/ckeditor/plugins/smiley/images/teeth_smile.gif" title="laugh">
```

After running through purifier with default settings:

```
<img alt="&quot;laugh&quot;" src="%5C" title="&quot;laugh&quot;">
```

I have tried changing the configuration settings; but I the src is never preserved.  Any thoughts?

Comment: With my psychic debugging powers I think you have magic quotes on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a suspicion that magic_quotes could be a reason..?

Also did you try `$config->set('Core.RemoveInvalidImg',true);`. Which version are you using? (Try older or newer)

Comment: I'm using version 4.1.1.  I tried using the suggested config setting but no luck.  I'm not running any other sanitization routines on the string, it is being stored to the database through a MySqli prepared statement.

Comment: I misread "magic quotes" for a call to mysql_escape_string.  You were absolutely right, my php.ini file was set to automatically escape quotes with the directive: magic_quotes_gpc set to ON.  Problem solved.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem.
This fixed it

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
function stripslashes_gpc(&$value)
{
    $value = stripslashes($value);
}
array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'stripslashes_gpc');
array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE, 'stripslashes_gpc');
array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
```

}

Comment: Worked, but don't forget to do addslashes() again before you save the string to your DB!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what htmlpurifier is, but the img tag you have there is perfectly legitimate (except it is unclosed) before running it.  After you run it, it is doubly escaping things and that just seems like garbage.  %5C is the url code for a backslash.  Seems like it is trying to escape the forward slash with a backslash and then it chokes.  What is this program?  Can I recommend [HTML Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/)?

Comment: Unary tags do not require a `/>` to close them in HTML; that's an XHTML idiom.

Comment: Why would you bother to make HTML that cannot be XHTML.  All XHTML can be HTML.  The reverse it not true because of the above, for example.

Comment: If you generate XHTML but send it with the wrong MIME type, then it is wrong HTML. A conformant SGML parser would display an <img/> as <img>/ with trailing slash. It just so happens that modern browsers have workarounds for HTML with trailing garbage (= which the slash is for text/html).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I started with HTML tidy but moved to purifier for XSS protection.  As far as the html/xhtml I'm limited to what CK editor produces in this case.  I may end up modifying it for a BB-code -like approach

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to an old post, I thought this little snippet might help others ending up here..

I fixed a multitude of unusual activity in my code to do with escaping characters by adding this line to my .htaccess file

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

From PHP documentation "This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0" http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php

Also, here are other ways to disable magic quotes
http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php